# Nginx password authentication keeps prompting for password

Tags: django, authentication, nginx, uwsgi

I want to upload a development branch of my website so that I can show it to clients and make tests in an environment as close to production as possible (with code that may not be ready for production). Thus I would like to password protect this site.

I'm developing a website using Django and use nginx for serving the website (with uWsgi). I manage to get prompted for password applying the following directives:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Content";  # also tried "Private Property"
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

But the problem is that after entering the first password properly, it keeps prompting me for the user & password again; as if every API call would need to be authenticated.

I think the issue might be with my configuration file, so here's my site.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name panel.mysite.dev;
    root /path/to/my/app/front/dist;

    ### I've also tried 'auth_basic' here

    location / {

        root /path/to/my/app/front/dist;
        index index.html;

        auth_basic "Private Property";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
    location /media {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://media.mysite.dev$1;
    }
    location /static {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://static.mysite.dev$1;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.mysite.dev;

    ### I've also tried 'auth_basic' here

    location /api {
        client_max_body_size 25m;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/api.mysite.dev.sock;
        include /path/to/my/app/back/uwsgi_params;
    }

}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name media.mysite.dev;
    root /path/to/my/app/media;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '.*\.mysite\.[com|dev]';

    location / {
        root /path/to/my/app/media;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name static.mysite.dev;
    root /path/to/my/app/static;
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*\.mysite\.[com|dev](:[0-9]+)?)) {
        set $cors "true";
    }
    location / {
        if ($cors = "true") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        }
    }
}
```

My question: Is there any way to remember the password once entered and allow authenticated users to navigate easily? Or am I missing something trivial?

EDIT:
In my django `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
```

Thank you very much in advance. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does your Django site by any chance also use HTTP authentication, but with a different user & password? (I'm asking because you wrote "API call"; Django REST framework does support [basic authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication)).

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. I accept both `TokenAuthentication` and `OAuth2Authentication` (I edited the question adding the authentication-related settings in case it helps). Is that right? Or could I restrict all petitions from my django configuration (not only the ones that require authentication (which I handle with Django Rest Framework), but all, taking into account that I don't want the site to be exposed at all?

Comment: Then there's your conflict: Both the basic HTTP authentication and `TokenAuthentication` use the `Authorization` header, and both will complain if they see the header of the other (which is, from their point of view, invalid). Is `SessionAuthentication` an option?

Comment: I would say no, since I am already using it in production. However, since access to this development server will be restricted, I guess I can change the settings. Nice. I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: Not related to django but sometimes it can be a cache issue. Test in incognito mode to check.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Basic authentication uses the `Authorization` header to transmit user and password. Django REST [also uses this header in the `TokenAuthentication` authentication backend](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py). Nginx [does not support multiple `Authorization` headers](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L145), so if you try to login and use Token authentication simultaneously, things will break.

A solution requiring no changes to the Django app would be to use another means of authentication in nginx, e.g., [client certificates](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client), or, you can use the [`ngx_http_auth_request_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) to check whether a signed session cookie is set/valid or if the request IP is in a (temporary) whitelist, and redirect the user to a page with a login form otherwise.

Comment: ^ best answer ever, saved me prolly HOURS of debugging

Comment: for the client certificates, I think [this is a really nice article](https://fardog.io/blog/2017/12/30/client-side-certificate-authentication-with-nginx/)!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent, easy and more secured way for Basic Authentication with Nginx. It is, use [oAuth2_proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) which has Basic Authentication support including a web form (excellent, browser will not keep connection alive) to input user/password credentials with option to include a password file like htpasswd. It also has support for many other identity providers.
Here's my oAuth2_proxy config file for Basic Auth:

```
http_address = "0.0.0.0:5160" #use any port you want

upstreams = [
    "https://url-that-you-want-to-protect/"
]

request_logging = false
custom_sign_in_logo = "/etc/apache2/small-email-icon.png" #custom logo on form
authenticated_emails_file = "/etc/apache2/emails" #required option, file can be empty

htpasswd_file = "/etc/apache2/.htpasswd" #basic auth password file
display_htpasswd_form = true

client_id = "hfytr76r7686887"
client_secret = "ghgh6767ghgh7654fghj6543dfgh5432"
cookie_name = "_oauth2_proxy"
cookie_secret = "ghgh6gguujgh7654fghj6543dfgh5432"
cookie_expire = "2h15m0s"
# cookie_refresh = ""
cookie_secure = true
footer = "Unauthorized access prohibited."
```