# How to check if the request header contains authorization in nginx

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I've read on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057631/nginx-password-authentication-keeps-prompting-for-password) that Nginx does not support multiple Authorization headers.

I was wondering if how I would check in the http request if an
authorization header is present.

basically I am adding a basic auth to my webpage since its not ready for production yet. My site is a single page application and I have successfully added authentication in the index page, but my site has also log in feature. When I log in it keeps asking for the authentication again. Im new to nginx and I am not quite sure how to get around with this

```
 location / {

        root /path/to/my/app/root/folder;
        index index.html index.php;

        #I want to only executed these lines only on the index page and login page 
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to see the headers:

```
$ curl -v -u your_user_name "http://......."
```

Look for the `> Authorization: Basic ...` line which contains a `Base64` encoding of `user:pass`.

You can decode the string using:

```
printf auth_string | base64 --decode
```

More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol).

---

Also, make sure `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` has the right permissions for `nginx` to be able to read it and that it contains your user/pass credentials in a format recognized by `nginx` ([info here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)):

**1. Plain text:**

> ```
>     # comment
>     name1:password1
>     name2:password2:comment
>     name3:password3
> ```

**2. Encrypted/hashed:**

> - encrypted with the crypt() function; can be generated using the    “htpasswd” utility from the Apache HTTP Server distribution or the
>   “openssl passwd” command;
> - hashed with the Apache variant of the MD5-based password algorithm    (apr1); can be generated with the same tools;
> - specified by the “{scheme}data” syntax (1.0.3+) as described in [RFC    2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307#section-5.3); currently implemented schemes include PLAIN (an
>   example one,    should not be used), SHA (1.3.13) (plain SHA-1
>   hashing, should not be    used) and SSHA (salted SHA-1 hashing, used
>   by some software packages,    notably OpenLDAP and Dovecot).

```
$ htpasswd 
Usage:
    htpasswd [-cimBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username
    htpasswd -b[cmBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username password

    htpasswd -n[imBdps] [-C cost] username
    htpasswd -nb[mBdps] [-C cost] username password
 -c  Create a new file.
 -n  Don't update file; display results on stdout.
 -b  Use the password from the command line rather than prompting for it.
 -i  Read password from stdin without verification (for script usage).
 -m  Force MD5 encryption of the password (default).
 -B  Force bcrypt encryption of the password (very secure).
 -C  Set the computing time used for the bcrypt algorithm
     (higher is more secure but slower, default: 5, valid: 4 to 31).
 -d  Force CRYPT encryption of the password (8 chars max, insecure).
 -s  Force SHA encryption of the password (insecure).
 -p  Do not encrypt the password (plaintext, insecure).
 -D  Delete the specified user.
 -v  Verify password for the specified user.
On other systems than Windows and NetWare the '-p' flag will probably not work.
The SHA algorithm does not use a salt and is less secure than the MD5 algorithm.
```